# How to filter a list of an nargs argument in argparse?

Tags: python, argparse

Let's imaging I have a CLI with an `nargs="*"` argument called `--list`. I would like to filter out certain elements of the this list.

For instance, if the user passes in `--list foo bar foo baz` I would like to filter out all `values == "foo"` so that the final list becomes `["bar", "baz"]`:

```py
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument(
    "--list",
    nargs="*",
)
parser.parse_args(["--list", "foo", "bar", "foo", "baz"])
```

I could obviously solve that in a post-processing step on the resulting args. However I was wondering if there is a **built-in mechanism** in argparse that allows to implement such a filter without post-postprocessing.

I tried to use `type=lambda: ...` but that seems to be called only on the values themselves instead of the final list, so I cannot use it for filtering values I suppose?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a parameter [`action`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#action) for `argparse.add_argument`. From the docs:

> ArgumentParser objects associate command-line arguments with actions. These actions can do just about anything with the command-line arguments associated with them, though most actions simply add an attribute to the object returned by parse_args().

So we can do the filtering with an `action`. The documentation states:

> The recommended way to create a custom action is to extend [`Action`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.Action), overriding the `__call__` method and optionally the `__init__` and `format_usage` methods.

A filtering `argparse.Action` could look like this:

```py
import argparse
from typing import Optional, Callable


class FilterNargsAction(argparse.Action):
    def __init__(
        self,
        option_strings,
        dest,
        nargs: Optional[str] = None,
        condition: Optional[Callable] = None,
        **kwargs
    ):
        if nargs not in ("*", "+"):
            # We could also allow integers 
            raise ValueError("nargs must be one of (*, +)")
        if condition is None:
            raise ValueError("condition needs to be set")
        self.condition = condition
        super().__init__(option_strings, dest, nargs=nargs, **kwargs)

    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        setattr(namespace, self.dest, [v for v in values if self.condition(v)])


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument(
    "--list",
    nargs="*",
    action=FilterNargsAction,
    condition=lambda x: x != "foo",
)
args = parser.parse_args(["--list", "foo", "bar", "foo", "baz"])

print(args.list)
```

If you absolutely need to filter arguments when parsing, you can use a custom `action`.